# hard wired remote WiFi access point

Tags: wireless-networking, remote, wireless-access-point

I have a 1 gig netgear router connected to a 1 gig netgear switcher & then patched to my distribution throughout the house.  My router is in the basement & I would like to have a ethernet hard wired remote access at a high point in my house for better coverage.  What is the best solution or equipment for this.  I do not need the remote access to be a switch.

Comment: Can you please clarify on what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to setup wireless access point on the second floor, but you don't have wired connection to the second floor? What remote access are you talking about.

Comment: I have a cat6 line up to the second floor which will give me much better coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a wireless range extender or a wireless router (with DHCP turned off).
In either case, it's wired to your network with a LAN cable, to bridge your wireless connections to the basement. Both are going to give you unused ethernet jacks for now, but potentially usable in the future.

Comment: I actually only need an access point without it being a switcher if they make one.